# strange warning: std::string::find returns size_t, but it could be npos

Tags: c++, string, stl

I have the following compiler  (g++ (GCC) 4.1.2 20071124) warning

"comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions"

```
 string a_str = ...

 if(a_str.rfind("<CDATA") == string::npos ) ...
```

Which is weird. Why would something so standard produce a warning?

Comment: Are you sure, that this produces the error?

Comment: `rfind()` returns `size_t` and `npos` is also `size_t`, it's very unlikely that this is the warning..

Comment: Can you post a small compilable code sample that reproduces the problem? Perhaps something like [this](http://ideone.com/yjCY8).

Comment: @Nim Technically it's `std::string::size_type`, which is `size_type` from the allocator, which is `size_t`. :)

Comment: It was just me, looking for an hour at the wrong file. 
Sorry about that.I'll remove the question.